# Deleting Entire word in a MultiAutoCompleteTextview

Tags: android, cpu-word, multiautocompletetextview

I want to delete entire word in a string.But my requirement is different. I want to do like whats app group contacts tagging delete. Here I have one time line page like facebook, whenever the user clicks an option to edit the post we can get that post along with tagged user names previously. If we click on back button then entire that tagged name should delete like whats app tag delete. I have No idea how to do this.Can any one help me out of this.

Thank you so much in advance.